# My button is not navigating me back to my page

Tags: button, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I am building a sign up page and when I click either the login button or the back button it is not taking me back to the login page.
This is the variable:

```
@Binding var showSignup: Bool
```

Here is my code for the back button:

```
Button(action: {
    showSignup = false
}, label: {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
        .font(.title2)
        .foregroundStyle(.gray)
})
```

Here is my code for the login button:

```
Button("Login"){
    showSignup = false
}
```

This is my login page:

```
struct JoinPage: View{
    @State private var showSignup: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            LoginPage(showSignup: $showSignup)
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showSignup) {
                    SignUp(showSignup: $showSignup)
                }
        }
   }
}
```

I have no clue why the variable is not flipping to false when I set it equal to false. Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your flow, how do you bind `showSignup` into 3 places like this? It seems like a conflict.

Comment: i just define it at the top of every file before the View. I define it on my joinpage and then bind it to my signup and login page.

Comment: Your JoinPage and LoginPage are the same view, LoginPage is a content view of JoinPage, right? And how can it work if `showSignup` is always false like this? There must be a trigger `true` somewhere.

Comment: where do you suggest that I trigger it true?

Comment: wait i ended up using a navigation link instead of the showSignup variable. However, I want to use a navigationlink on the arrow image how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding `showSignup` into 3 sub-views without any `true` trigger, so I think that's why it didn't work. Following by your comments, I'm assuming this:

```swift
//Going back from SignUp -> JoinPage
Button("Login") {
    showSignup = true
}
```

However, to make it simpler and more readable, I recommend using `@Environment(\.dismiss)` and removing the `showSignup` binding.

```swift
struct SignUp: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        ...
        Button("Login"){
            dismiss()
        }
        
        Button(action: {
            dismiss()
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                .font(.title2)
                .foregroundStyle(.gray)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much the environment way worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome.